# When to use zip() instead of zipWith() RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

Is there any semantic difference in pairwise composing with `zip()` vs. `zipWith(`) in RxJava?  Is the choice between the static zip and the .zipWith purely stylistic?

Answer (score 29):

Convenience and context.

The static `zip` is useful when you have two sources already assembled and now you want to zip them together. Most of the time they are themselves long chains or come from all over the place.

```
Observable<T1> source1 = op().op().op().op().op();
Observable<T2> source2 = op().op().op().op().op();

Observable.zip(source1, source2, (a, b) -> a + b);
```

The instance `zipWith` is useful when one of the sources is longer while the other is shorter. At that point, it is more convenient to zip with the shorter one.

```
public Observable<R> withIndex(Observable<T> source, Func2<Integer, T, R> func) {
    return source.zipWith(Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE),
         (t, idx) -> func(idx, t));
}
```

Comment: "At that point, it is more convenient to zip with **the shorter one**." Is it necessary that if `a.zipWith(b)` then `a.length() <= b.length()`?